# Error: Git "Error deploying the application"

Tags: xcode, git

I'm using Git to mount an app to Scalingo, but when I do "git push scalingo master" it shows me this:

XXXXX+AAAA@AAAA MINGW32 ~/Desktop/Scalingo (master)
$ git push scalingo master

Counting objects: 1120, done.

Delta compression using up to 4 threads.

Compressing objects: 100% (1043/1043), done.

Writing objects: 100% (1120/1120), 16.71 MiB | 1.53 MiB/s, done.

Total 1120 (delta 208), reused 0 (delta 0)

<-- Start deployment of vinumtest -->

```
   Fetching source code

   Fetching deployment cache
```

-----> Installing requirements with pip

```
   You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help
```

install")

Build complete, shipping your container...

Waiting for your application to boot...

!   Error deploying the application

!   → Your application has stopped unexpectedly when starting

!   Read the output and fix your code accordingly

!   Common errors:       http://doc.scalingo.com/deployment/start-
error#crashed

!   Need help? Email us: support@scalingo.com

To git@scalingo.com:test.git

! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)

error: failed to push some refs to 'git@scalingo.com:test.git'

The actual result is that I cant do the command "git push scalingo master"

Answer (score 2):

As the message in the deployment is telling you:

```
   You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")
```

It seems that your requirements.txt does not contain any dependency. All the Python modules you're using should be listed in this file.

What kind of application are you trying to deploy?

Whatever is the app, you have to ensure that your application is working on your local workstation before deploying it.

Regards,

-- Léo